# Back button not working in sencha touch

Tags: google-chrome, sencha-touch-2

Back button of sencha touch(touch version 2.1.1.594) is not working in latest chrome (version 46.0.2490.71). How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post some code or give some more specifics

Comment: this is not complete information of issue. Did you asking for Navigation view back button?